# Graph Theory - Looking for algorithms to solve this

Tags: algorithm, graph

In the project I am currently working on there is a problem that can be modelled as a graph problem; I tend to refer to it as the 'Delivery Problem'.
Because I am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel, I am asking whether there exists a similar problem to the one I am about to present and / or algorithms that could solve it or could play a role.

I will spare any readers from formal mathematics as it can often hinder comprehensibility:

Suppose there is a courier carrying a set of items; each item has an identification and an amount. Also suppose there is a set of storages that the courier can go to. Each storage can only store items that have certain identifications. Furthermore, storages have a maximum amount they can store - a capacity. The identifications accepted and capacity are arbitrary for every storage. Upon the courier reaching a storage, all items that can fit into it are transferred from the courier.

A little more formally, suppose a weighted, complete graph in which all vertices represent a storage; V0 is a storage that accepts no items and the starting location of the courier. A solution is a path in which the maximum amount of items is transferred. An optimal solution is the shortest path in which the maximum amount of items is transferred.

I am looking for an algorithm that yields 'good' solutions; with 'good' solution I mean solutions that have reasonably short paths. I am aware that the problem is NP-Complete as it is reducible to the Traveling Salesman problem.

(Edit:)
The specific problem I have allows the following assumptions:

Suppose a function #capacity(id) where 'id' is the identification of an item; it returns the maximum amount of items with the identification 'id' which can be stored across all storages. The function has a time complexity of O(1).

Suppose a function #count_storages(id) where 'id' is the identification of an item; it counts the number of storages which can store an item with the identification 'id'. The function has a time complexity of O(1).

The total number n of storages is at most 150. The total number d of distinct items is at most 40.

Comment: This problem is easily reduceable from Traveling Salesman Problem (and thus NP-Complete).

Comment: Do I understand right, that the courier does not have to visit all storages? How big is your problem, how many storages do you have to consider?

Comment: @ead It is not required for the courier to visit all storages. It is required that the maximum possible amount of items is transferred to storages, however. So yes, you are right. The maximum amount of items that can be transferred can be determined in O(1) using the #capacity function for all item identifications. I have edited the post to provide more assumptions.